# Force the www rewrite cond issue

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, no-www

I am trying to redirect my example.com to WWW.example.com for this I have used some code in .ht-access file

the code is

```
    # Force the "www."
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.topseonow\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.topseonow.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But after this code change I am facing some problem in browser . getting error message

error message:
The www.topseonow.com page isn’t working
www.topseonow.com 
redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies

where I am wrong

**note: this domain is addon domain**

Comment: n number of time i am getting with www and without www site URL in network section

Comment: Then you need to investigate what is causing redirect to `non-www` in your config/code/rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and restart the server,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.topseonow.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.topseonow.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: facing same problem :(